# Power function [pow()] always giving a ZERO as result

Tags: c, pow

Power function always giving a zero(0) as result no matter the input.

I am learning the power function, but it doesn't work.please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int A,B; 
    int C=pow(A,B);
    printf("To find power please enter values of A and B \n");
    printf( "Please enter value of A: \n");
    scanf("%d",&A);
    printf("Please enter value of B: \n");
    scanf("%d",&B);
    printf("The power of A and B is : %d",C);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you think should happen first: figuring out the values to use, or doing the math with them? Therefore, how should the code be ordered? What do you think should happen, if the code tries to calculate an exponent, before it knows what number to use for the base or the exponent? Why?

Comment: C is not Microsoft Excel.  When you say `C = pow(A, B);` you are asking for that calculation to be performed once, *at the time control flow reaches it*.  You are *not* setting things up so that for the rest of time, no matter what values A and B take on, C will be set to A^B.

Comment: Exactly -- ask yourself what are the value of `A` and `B` at the time `pow()` is called.  They are both uninitialized variables of automatic storage duration -- your use of them while uninitialized invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the value of C before you assign the A and C values.

Put `int C = pow(a, b);` right before you run `printf("The power of A and B is : %d",C);`

**Complete code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int A, B;
    printf("To find power please enter values of A and B \n");
    printf("Please enter value of A: \n");
    scanf("%d", &A);
    printf("Please enter value of B: \n");
    scanf("%d", &B);
    int C = pow(A, B);
    printf("The power of A and B is : %d", C);
    return 0;
}
```

The tag powershell seems random, you should have the tag set to the language that you're using.

Comment: You also need to use the `pow()` function here as `int C = (int)round(pow(A, B));` The `pow()` function often isn't very accurate, and you might truncate the result of `pow(5, 3)` from `124.999999` t0 `124`.

Answer (score -2):

I just now moved the
Int C=pow(A,B);
line just before
printf("The power of A and B is : %d",C);
Basically moved it from top to bottom.
And it worked!

Comment: Now ask yourself, why that is. Just FYI: There's been a study on programmer aptitude, that was using the kind of confusion you went through to differentiate between people who are thinking in mathematical equations that are not subject to mutable state (assignments) over time. If you're thinking this way, maybe look into functional languages like [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) or [Clean](https://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean)